# Meteor Highcharts using collection data

Tags: mongodb, meteor, highcharts

I'm trying to display a piechart using the Highchart package for Meteor.
I've got it working with a static data source, like this:

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Sales',
            data: 
              [  
                 ["Norway", 123123.32],
                 ["Canada", 1977844.86],
                 ["France", 2644017.71],
                 ["Denmark", 28954612.34],
                 ["United Kingdom", 3391712.21],
                 ["United States", 9389789.51]
              ]
        }]
```

in the series part of the .js of the template file.

But when I'm trying to use MongoDb's find statement it either shows no data or the report is showing up weirdly, I guess this is due to the formatting of the data resulted from the find query.

My data in the collection is looking something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "HsgEBrrSvBp6qzp8Q", "0" : "Norway", "1" : 9061000.58 }
{ "_id" : "5dvtddEogj6d5Zw7D", "0" : "Canada", "1" : 1977844.86 }
{ "_id" : "6XmfgjBG4dupes3ma", "0" : "France", "1" : 2644017.71 }
{ "_id" : "BB8Av8GRpPXPsWfzj", "0" : "Denmark", "1" : 2894312.34 }
{ "_id" : "44qbHdtA3wTtf9QFL", "0" : "United Kingdom", "1" : 3391712.21 }
{ "_id" : "YqyWGzXkT4pD532qJ", "0" : "United States", "1" : 9389789.51 }
```

I've also tried to only find the selected fields ("0" and "1")

```
SalesData.find({}, {_id:0}).fetch()
```

Anyone got any tips on how to get the data from a collection in a format that can be used in Highcharts?!

Thanks!

EDIT: I solved it by pushing the required values to an array and set that array as data source.

```
var seriesData = [];
  var reportData = SalesData.find({});

  reportData.forEach(function(countryData) {
    var dataPoint = [countryData.Country, countryData.Total];
    seriesData.push(dataPoint);
    console.log(countryData.Country);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can convert the result from a find query directly into an array of values by using [cursor.map](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map).

Here is an example for your scenario (using ecmascript2015)

```
SalesData.find({}, {fields: {Country: 1, Total: 1}}).fetch().map((countryData) =>
{
  {return [countryData.Country, countryData.Total]}
})
```

You should be able to get the data source format needed by highchart

Answer (score 1):

db result is a collection of **objects** (curly braces on each row). While the static data is an **array** of values (rectangular braces). So, you need to convert each row in db into array of values.

here is the mapping code:

```
var ds = [
    { "_id" : "HsgEBrrSvBp6qzp8Q", "0" : "Norway", "1" : 9061000.58 },
    { "_id" : "5dvtddEogj6d5Zw7D", "0" : "Canada", "1" : 1977844.86 },
    { "_id" : "6XmfgjBG4dupes3ma", "0" : "France", "1" : 2644017.71 },
    { "_id" : "BB8Av8GRpPXPsWfzj", "0" : "Denmark", "1" : 2894312.34 },
    { "_id" : "44qbHdtA3wTtf9QFL", "0" : "United Kingdom", "1" : 3391712.21 },
    { "_id" : "YqyWGzXkT4pD532qJ", "0" : "United States", "1" : 9389789.51 }
];

var asValueArray = ds.map(function(row){
    return [row["0"],row["1"]];
});
```

Then, you just assign it to your series object:

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Sales',
        data: asValueArray 
        }]
```

Comment: Db data actually has 6 "fields" by 3 of the are "columns" or what you might call them ("0" and "1" should be named "Country" and "Total" instead, but I doubt that has anything to do with my problem). With my query SalesData.find({}, {_id:0}).fetch() I am trying to only select the relevant fields, but the result also includes the "0" and "1" (as column fields and I haven't found a way to get those excluded.

Comment: I apologize if I'm stating the obvious, but here is the link on how to fetch selected columns from the document. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/. All you need is the names of the columns

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I'm doing in this query:
SalesData.find({}, {_id:0}).fetch()
I chose to exclude the _id field, but the result is still containing the "column" fields "0" and "1". I have looked through the MongoDB doc's but haven't really found anything that helps me. But I've seen examples where a find query have been used to populate a Highchart data field so it should not be impossible...

Comment: If I'm reading your query correctly, you're removing only the `_id` field. You need to do the same for each field you want to hide. Like `{ _id:0, fldName:0}`.

Comment: The thing is, I want to keep the data assigned to the fields "0" and "1", but not the "0" and "1" themself. This query "find({},{_id:0, "0":0, "1":0}" would only return an empty row for each row in the db. You see what I mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that 0 and 1 are the column names. Have you tried to convert the row object to an array of values?

Comment: Yes. That's how I solved it! Created an array and pushed the values to it.